# in oozie installation, while creating ooziedb Iam getting the following error

Tags: oozie

Command:

> wcbdd@ubuntu:~/apache/oozie-4.1.0/distro/target/oozie-4.1.0/bin$ sudo -u oozie ./ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql –run

```
setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"

Validate DB Connection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:374)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.<init>(Services.java:110)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.getJdbcConf(OozieDBCLI.java:163)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:845)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:853)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:181)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:125)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Hadoop libraries are missing in the `libserver` or `lib` directory. How did you build the Oozie tar? Also you can try by adding the hadoop lib into classpath.

Comment: I built the oozie tar using the mkdistro command. In which lib directory, I must place the hadoop libraries. Aslo please tell me how to add the hadoop lib into classpath. Iam new to Linux.

Comment: I believe a simple way would be using oozie profiles. While building the tar include these maven options `-DskipTests -Phadoop-2,uber`. If you are running hadoop 1 use that profile. Also note the Oozie will bring hadoop-2.4.0 for hadoop-2 profile.

Comment: its not working

Comment: please tell me any alternative

Comment: Is there any change in the error? Also did you check that, new build lib have the hadoop libraries.

Comment: `bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war;
bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://host:8020 -locallib oozie-sharelib-*.tar.gz -concurrency 5;
bin/oozied.sh start;
tail -f logs/oozie.log;`

Comment: I solved this error by doing these things "Install common io class and configuration class in libext.

Install hadoop-lzo-0.4.1.3 in libext

Start the hadoop service by executing the command

run start-all.sh". Thanks for the help

Comment: That is great. I believe you have tested by running couple of workflows. Thanks.

Comment: sudo -u oozie ./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://host:8020 -locallib oozie-sharelib-*.tar.gz

Error: E0902: Exception occured: [Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]

Comment: It is not able to connect with HDFS. Can you check it is running and host and port are correct in the oozie share lib command.

Comment: how to check that. Please tell me

Comment: hdfs is not running. I tried several ports. Oozie is running.

Comment: Probably you have not started the HDFS service. Please check the respective document. One useful command is `jps` to find the running services.

Comment: how to start the HDFS service

Comment: Thanks. It is working f ine.

Comment: It would be write down those steps here as answer which solved your problem. Thanks.